# ERC token multiple address sending

Tags: tokens, erc-20, myetherwallet

Hi is it possible to send token XYZQ to two addresses in one transaction. here is example. 100 XYZQ ===> 99.9999 to XYZQ 1 address and 0.0001 XYZQ to second XYZQ address? For same amount of gas

Comment: It seems like you want to batch an Ethereum transaction, but at what level are you looking to do the batching? Are you trying to make a single transaction go to two addresses? Or are you trying to set up a Web3 client call which will generate two transactions? or something else?

Answer (score 0):

> For same amount of gas

This doesn't work. The gas price will be higher, as you are doing one transaction more.

That being said, it shouldn't be a problem to write a simple solidity contract to execute two transactions.